# Best data security cache settings in windows Intel Rapid Storage Technology for Raid 1 and Raid 0

Tags: windows-10, raid, raid-1, intel-rst, hard-drive-cache

I have

raid 0 - 2 x SSD - used as windows disk

raid 1 - 2 x 4 TB storage - used as data backup extremely important

I am rather interested in best data security and reliability rather than speed

Here my settings are they best selection for data security and reliability?

Using windows 10

Raid 0 settings as below

[image]

Raid 1 settings as below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
You have both flushing enabled and write through, as opposed to write behind.

You wouldn't want to have the raid0 run faster, with a slightly higher risk ?